# Website Not Functioning Properly When Opened With Chrome Driver Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browser, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

Made an automation script using Python.
Script should basically copy records from CSV file and then go and paste it on a specific website.
The script works fine and it does its job.
But... There is a major unexpected error...
Selenium websdriver when it access the site that I defined for it and then logs in with my credentials to my account.
I find a major difference in the account. All account history of anything that I did before does not show up at all. So I basically can't see any previous records that I submitted manually before.
Also, I have credit points on this site. I have about 1000 credit points, when webdriver opened my account, it shows ZERO credit points.

When I access my account normally from the regular browser, my account looks fine and showing all credit and records.

How to fix such an issue?

I tried to add wait time to let the page load, probably this was the issue.
Still didn't work. All records and credit does not appear.

I tried to add maximize function to maximize an already existing window of Chrome.
Still did not work and Selenium keeps opening a new webdriver window

I tried Firefox webdriver and phantomJS. Still sailed and site does not show proper info.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution until I visited the website and tried it myself.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)